# Make More button in tabbed bar application slide out in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbar

This is a simple question. So I have a tabbed bar application with a `More...` tab button. I was wondering if it's possible to make the `More...` button be a slide out menu button? I found tutorials on how to do it on a regular app design but things get a little more complicated when it comes to the tabbed bar application.

Comment: What is a "slide out menu button"?

Comment: Well it's more of an action than a button. It's like the Facebook app. When you press the menu button the main screen slides to the right to reveal the navigation. I want to do that but with the more button that is on the bottom of the tabbed bar application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you don't own the More button in the tab bar of a UITabBarController, so you can't control what happens. (You can access the navigation controller that appears when the More button is tapped, but it's still going to be just another view controller whose view is displayed above the tab bar.) If you want to write a new interface you'll have to write a *whole* new interface, i.e. don't use the built-in UITabBarController. That's no big deal; it isn't doing anything you can't manage to do yourself.